# Slow postgres query with multiple joins to same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

The following query is running very slowly for me:

```
    SELECT r.comp,b.comp,n.comp
      FROM paths AS p
INNER JOIN comps AS r ON (p.root=r.id)
INNER JOIN comps AS b ON (p.base=b.id)
INNER JOIN comps AS n ON (p.name=n.id);
```

Running EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE) gives the following result:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/iKG

Is it (re)building a hash for the `comps` table for each alias?  Anything I can do to make this faster?  Note: running two separate queries to join the data myself is faster.

Postgres version: 9.1.9
Machine: Ubuntu 12.04 8 | 4-core Xeon 2.5Ghz | 8GB of RAM

```
archiving=> \d+ comps
                                     Table "public.comps"
 Column |  Type  |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  | Description 
--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id     | bigint | not null default nextval('comps_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 comp   | text   | not null                                           | extended | 
Indexes:
    "comps_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "comps_comp_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (comp)
    "comps_comp_idx" btree (comp)
    "comps_id_idx" btree (id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `comps.id` ?

Comment: Not explicitly, but the schema has it as "id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY"
so it should be indexed anyway as it is a key, no?

Comment: Your query returns 18370459 rows. Of course, that's slow, what would you expect? Chances are, you need a different query, but you kept your actual objectives a secret.

Comment: My objective is to process the entire list, that's my objective.  I'm not complaining that it's slow exactly, but that it seems to be building three hashes for the same table.  I'm not sure though, hence my questions: "Am I right? Anything I can do to fix this?"  Let me put this another way, building the hash myself and doing the join manually (using two queries) is faster.

Comment: You did not even provide your version of Postgres nor the table definition or a test case. That's a **no go** for performance questions. [Consider this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That link was much more helpful than your first response, thanks.  Updated the original question.  It's OK if the answer is simply "No".  I'm just curious as to what's going on.

Comment: @Obtuse: Postgres has no any special optimization for selfjoins - so it is expected behave.

Comment: @PavelStehule  Thanks.  If you repost the comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have any special optimizations for seljoin - so it is expected behavior.